# php syntax, the operator =&

Tags: php, syntax

I have a question about the PHP syntax.Below is the php code:

```
$err = $campaign =& $this->_setCampaign($mission['campaign_id'])
```

what does the "=&" mean? I had googled but since google doesn't support for searching these marks.Is it something about the assign by reference issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a reference operator.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php for more details.

Comment: You're welcome, and if mine or other answers help you please don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's assignment by reference. Read more in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php).

Comment: Thank u for the link,it is useful to me.